# Problem with rotating custom inputView for UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, inputview

I've written a custom input view that is meant to be used to replace the standard keyboard for a `UITextView`.  If I assign my custom `UIView` as my `UITextView`'s `inputView`, it works as expected in both portrait and landscape mode.

The problem occurs when I rotate the device - whenever I do this, my custom `UIView` expands to fill the entire screen, instead of just covering up the keyboard.  I don't have any custom resizing code anywhere for this - I'm literally just assigning the UIView as the UITextView's inputView property and then rotating the device.

How do I get my custom keyboard view to only occupy the space taken up by the normal keyboard when I rotate the device?

Answer (score 5):

From Apple docs:

> You have a lot of flexibility in defining the size and content of an input view or input accessory view. Although the height of these views can be what you’d like, they should be the same width as the system keyboard. If UIKit encounters an input view with an UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight value in its autoresizing mask, it changes the height to match the keyboard.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1

Answer (score 2):

The `autoresizingMask` is `UIViewAutoresizingNone` by default if I remember. You `autoresizingMask` should be `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`.

Comment: That doesn't work either - the view still takes up the whole screen as soon as I rotate.

Comment: I'm going to put together a test app to see if I can replicate this problem simply.

Comment: Well, your code works perfectly in my simple test app, so I've got some other problem, I guess. I hate inheriting other people's applications.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. The way to fix this is:

1. Open the viewcontroller .m file of the keyboard
2. Find the `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` method
3. Make it return NO.

My guess is that the view was doing a double rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Make your inputViews autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone; 
Playing with different values of autoresizingMask (version specific) shall help.

Here are some details , which i worked out some time back for iPad (may be this will help you):

1. If input view is a Picker view, autoresizing happens by default, which means
   the frame is set to required rect. There is a little discrepancy in the way this is done in different Targets/Versions for iPad:

   1. `autoresizemask` should at least be `autoresizeflexiblewidth` in all targets.
   2. Rect set to `default(initial)` height if `autoresizeflexibleheight` is not enabled in iPad3.2
   3. Rect set to improper coordinates (x,y) if `autoresizeflexibleheight` is set in iPad4 do not use `autoresizeflexibleheight` mask for picker view.
2. If `inputview` is not a picker view, its `autoresizemasks` for `flexibleheight` should be turned off.

Comment: This makes it take up the entire screen immediately, which isn't what I want.